# Iterate randomly through entire list while checking condition

Tags: python, iteration, conditional-statements

I want to iterate through a list randomly until a condition is met. However, I also want to go through every item in the list (randomly!) before I repeat any items. What's the best way to to this?

Here's what I thought of:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
random.shuffle(letters)

index = 0

while somecondition:
    dosomethingwith letters[index % len(letters)]
    alter somecondition
    index += 1

    if index == len(letters):
        random.shuffle(letters)
```

Is there some way to do this without using an index?

Comment: Can I ask why do you want to do this? Secondly why don't you shuffle the list like you did and just iterate through the whole shuffled list? Just shuffle the list every time you want to iterate?

Comment: Because I want to iterate through each item in the list before I do any repeats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
done = False
while not done:
    random.shuffle(letters)

    for letter in letters:
        if somecondition:
            done = True
            break
```

Note that this will repeatedly change the order of traversal after all items have been visited, which I'm assuming is what you're looking for.

If you instead want one fixed (but still random) order, then you could simply perform `random.shuffle(letters)` once before entering the loop, instead of on each iteration.

Comment: I can't upvote this, but it's sorta what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Ellburrito Glad I could help. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to encapsulate the idea of "iterate randomly":

```
def randomly(seq):
    shuffled = list(seq)
    random.shuffle(shuffled)
    return iter(shuffled)
```

then:

```
for i in randomly(letters):
    #.. we're good to go ..
```

Comment: I also want to check the condition every time I get a new letter.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a list continuously, use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
for c in itertools.cycle(letters):
  if somecondition:
    ...
    break
```

If you need it to be in a new random order each time, you can replicate the behavior of `cycle()` easily enough:

```
def random_cycle(ls):
  local_ls = ls[:] # defensive copy
  while True:
    random.shuffle(local_ls)
    for e in local_ls:
      yield e
```

e.g.:

```
>>> list(islice(random_cycle([1, 2, 3, 4]), 20))
[1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

You might also like [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) or [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) for applying your conditional.